# Create XML using array of JSON values as input - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml, xsd

I have an array of JSON values (article numbers), which can vary in size from 1- couple of hundred items (article numbers).

Based on that array, i would need to create an XML where parts of these article numbers would need to be entered. The first 6 digits are always the same for each article, and should come under tag ipc:familyVersion. Then, for each article, the next 4 digits should come under ipc:characteristic, and the last 3 under ipc:value. The xml should produce a ipc:charValue tag for eacht article number.

```
This is the JSON array (6 items as an example, but always varies)

[
   '117101-1100-005',
  '117101-1640-015',
  '117101-1650-005',
  '117101-5100-005',
  '117101-7850-040',
  '117101-7900-005'
]

This is the XML i would need to produce (desired output):

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ipc="http://kiongroup.com/sapIpcService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ipc:sapIpcRequest>
         <ipc:wsTransferBean>
           
            <ipc:function>i</ipc:function>
            <ipc:language>en</ipc:language>
            <ipc:familyVersion>**117101**</ipc:familyVersion>
                               <ipc:style>s</ipc:style>
                                               <ipc:charValue>
                                                               <ipc:characteristic>**1100**</ipc:characteristic>
                                                               <ipc:value>**105**</ipc:value>
                                               </ipc:charValue>
                                               <ipc:charValue>
                                                               <ipc:characteristic>1640</ipc:characteristic>
                                                               <ipc:value>015</ipc:value>
                                               </ipc:charValue>
                                               <ipc:charValue>
                                                               <ipc:characteristic>1650</ipc:characteristic>
                                                               <ipc:value>005</ipc:value>
                                               </ipc:charValue>
                                               <ipc:charValue>
                                                               <ipc:characteristic>5100</ipc:characteristic>
                                                               <ipc:value>005</ipc:value>
                                               </ipc:charValue>
                                               <ipc:charValue>
                                                               <ipc:characteristic>7850</ipc:characteristic>
                                                               <ipc:value>040</ipc:value>
                                               </ipc:charValue>
                                                <ipc:charValue>
                                                               <ipc:characteristic>7900</ipc:characteristic>
                                                               <ipc:value>005</ipc:value>
                                               </ipc:charValue>
         </ipc:wsTransferBean>
      </ipc:sapIpcRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

This is the XSD:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://kiongroup.com/sapIpcService" targetNamespace="http://kiongroup.com/sapIpcService" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <element name="sapIpcRequest">
      <complexType>
         <sequence>
            <element name="wsTransferBean" type="tns:wsTransferBeanType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
         </sequence>
      </complexType>
   </element>
   <complexType name="wsTransferBeanType">
      <sequence>
         <element name="function" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="string" />
         <element name="language" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="string" />
         <element name="familyVersion" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="style" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="charValue" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" type="tns:charValueType" />
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="charValueType">
      <sequence>
         <element name="characteristic" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
         <element name="value" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <element name="sapIpcResponse">
      <complexType>
         <sequence>
            <element name="wsResultBean" type="tns:wsResultBeanType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
            <element name="wsErrorBean" type="tns:wsErrorBeanType" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
         </sequence>
      </complexType>
   </element>
   <complexType name="wsResultBeanType">
      <sequence>
         <element name="materialnumber" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="language" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="string" />
         <element name="statusOfCompletion" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="message" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="numberOfPossibleCharValuePairs" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="numberOfDefaultSystemCharValuePairs" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="numberOfRequiredChars" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" />
         <element name="lastAssignedCharValuePair" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" type="tns:charValueType" />
         <element name="requiredChars" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" type="string" />
         <element name="defaultSystemCharValuePairs" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" type="tns:charValueType" />
         <element name="possibleCharValuePairs" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" type="tns:charValueType" />
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="wsErrorBeanType">
      <sequence>
         <element name="errorMessages" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" type="string" />
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
</schema>
```

Comment: This is SOAP, look for a SOAP library/tutorial. XML is just the (internal) serialization format SOAP uses. That makes it possible to treat it as XML or basic text but the first approach should be using the specific tools for the format.

Answer (score 0):

Did it this way, maybe not the best way, but it works so far:

```
export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    
    const jsonObj = ["117101-1100-005","115202-1640-015","115202-1650-005","112000-5100-005","117101-7850-040","117101-7900-005"]
      let familyVersion = jsonObj[0].slice(0,6);
  const xml1 = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""+
"xmlns:ipc=\"http://kiongroup.com/sapIpcService\">"+
"<soapenv:Header/>"+
"<soapenv:Body>"+
"<ipc:sapIpcRequest>"+
"<ipc:wsTransferBean>"+
"<ipc:function>i</ipc:function>"+
"<ipc:language>en</ipc:language>"+
"<ipc:familyVersion>"+familyVersion+"</ipc:familyVersion>"+
"<ipc:style>s</ipc:style>";
;

let xmlFinal = xml1

    for (let obj of jsonObj){
      let characteristic = obj.slice(7,11);
      let value = obj.slice(12,15);
      let xmlBody = "<ipc:charValue><ipc:characteristic>"+characteristic+"</ipc:characteristic><ipc:value>"+value+"</ipc:value></ipc:charValue>"
      xmlFinal+=xmlBody
    }

    const xml2="</ipc:wsTransferBean>"+
"</ipc:sapIpcRequest>"+
"</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
xmlFinal+=xml2

return xmlFinal


  },
})
```